# 14ft wide wood gate construction

Tags: woodworking, fence, gates

I am putting a gate across my driveway which is 14ft between posts on either side. Its going to be wood and all 1x6 and 1x8 lumber to keep weight down. Each gate will be about 7ft long so I was thinking of putting a wheel at the end of both. I live in NH so Im sinking the post hole 4ft and the gate will be 4ft tall. Do I need to use a 6x6 and if so does the hole have to be 18in wide or can I do a 12in hole with a sonotube and concrete?

Comment: Related question: [What size posts do I need to use to build a wooden driveway gate?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/5519/2196) We may want to make the questions more generic (How should I support a wooden driveway gate?) and merge them.

Comment: VTC and Merge with http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/what-size-posts-do-i-need-to-use-to-build-a-wooden-driveway-gate as per BMitch.

Comment: The trick with a wheel is you need a fairly flat plane along the arc of the swing. I'd maybe consider looking into using some reinforcing airplane cable to reinforce.

Comment: Have you considered how the gate will open and the wheel will roll when snow covers the driveway?